# MATLAB to Python datestr

Tags: python, matlab, datetime

I have a MATLAB script that I would like to convert to Python. The MATLAB code is

```matlab
c = fix(clock);
t = 26912214.000820093;
t_str=datestr(t/24/60/60 + datenum(c(1),1,1),'yyyy_mm_dd_HH_MM_SS')
```

which returns

```
t_str =
    '2022_11_08_11_36_54'
```

I would like to limit solutions to only utilize the Python datetime library and not pd, numpy, etc.

Comment: If you have a solution to your question, please post it below in the answer box, not in the question itself. Thanks!

Comment: Your solution looks fine, just be careful with the timezone, I think Matlab uses UTC by default while Python defaults to *local time*

Answer (score 0):

I found that the Python equivalent is,

```py
import datetime
t = 26912214.000820093;
t_str = (datetime.datetime(datetime.datetime.now().year, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=t)).strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')
```

I would still greatly appreciate any suggestions or improvements.